# X is not a legal cursor attribute plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to find the gcd of two numbers using a recursive approach.
My function:

```
create or replace function gcd(a in number, b in number)
return number
as
begin
    if a = 0
    then return b;
    else return gcd(b % a, a);
    end if;
end;
/
```

I am calling it like this

```
declare
      a1 number;
      b1 number;
      z number;
begin
   a1:=25;
   b1:=40;
   z := gcd(a1,b1);
   dbms_output.put_line(z);
end;
```

It throws me this error:

> Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 15, column 14:
>   PLS-00208: identifier 'X' is not a legal cursor attribute
>   ORA-06550: line 15, column 4:   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Answer (score 3):

`b % a` is not valid Oracle syntax. If you want to calculate a modulus you need to use the Oracle MOD() function, that is `mod(b, a)`.

You get the `PLS-00208` error because Oracle uses the `%` symbol to reference cursor attributes like `%rowtype` or `%notfound`. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/index.htm).